# How can I convert numbers to hh:mm:ss in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to convert numbers into duration in Google Data Studio, however it's not showing the correct output.

[image: Image for Reference]

I want column A numbers in the form on Column B as an output, but in Google Data Studio it's showing the duration as 0:00:00.

Comment: Your number is below one. Formating a value to duration is possible. Then the value in seconds is translated in h:mm:ss  . Please try a bigger numer e.g. 75 --> 
00:01:15

Comment: [Formatted Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) are preferred to images of Tables as it can be [searched for and tested out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12892553) and in addition [Users from certain countries can't view hosted images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407369/12892553); additionally, a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) such as a publicly editable Google Sheet (with sample data) and a Report would allow users to more easily reproduce and test out the issue, along with suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You must create a custom field and use this as the formula:

Number*86400

then choose the type to be "Duration(sec.)"

Comment: I used the above formula Number*86400 and then I took the Average from the output.